# Equal time displacement correlation functions and their physical interpretation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, correlation-functions

Displacement correlation functions in question are within harmonic approximation and are derived for example in: A. Maradudin, Dynamical properties of solids 1, 1 (1974). Maradudin says about the displacement time correlation functions that: "The physical interpretation of these correlation functions is simple only in the classical limit" and "In the quantum limit these correlation functions become complex. Their imaginary parts reflect the noncommutativity of the operators appearing in them.".

If we restrict to equal time correlation functions, then displacement operators commute. Is the physical interpretation of these correlation functions same as the corresponding classical correlation functions? In general, if we have equal time correlation functions and the corresponding operators which commute, is their physical interpretation same as the corresponding classical correlation functions?

Direct calculation shows that, even the operators commute, the equal time correlation functions (their values) including two displacement operators corresponding to same atom within same cell are complex in the case, where cartesian components of displacement differ from each other. This is somewhat confusing.

Comment: What do you mean by "displacement operators"? Do you mean the operator corresponding to the displacement of an atom from its equilibrium - as in a phonon? What you are calling equal time correlations of commuting operators - isn't this just taking the product of expectation values? This is hard to answer without a little more detail and definitions.

Comment: Indeed, I mean displacement operator of an atom from its equilibrium position. These displacement operators can be essentially written in terms of phonon creation and annihilation operators.